# Obtaining PMF from a binomial distribution (Joint)

Tags: probability

$$X\sim\mathrm{binomial}(1, 1/3)\text{ and }Y\sim\mathrm{binomial}(2,1/2)$$

How can I get

$$W = XY+1$$

Normally I would attempt but this one I don't even know how to get started

Comment: $X$ only has two outcomes, $Y$ has three.  Draw a table with $X$'s outcomes going down the side and $Y$'s across the top.  Then at their intersections write their product and add $1$.  This gives you the sample space for $W$.  Can you figure out the product of each outcome?  I assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent here.

Comment: How did you know that X only has two outcomes and Y has three?

Comment: Usually, when a random variable $N\sim\mathbb{Bin}(n,p)$ then we say $N$ counts the number of successes after performing an independent experiment $n$ times.  This means that there could be $0, 1, 2, ..., n$ possible successes or **$n+1$** outcomes.

Comment: So the answer is basically a 2 by 3 table, with each tiles giving the probability given some X, Y, am i correct? And that probabiity coming from the product of [p(x)p(y)]+1

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
X \backslash Y & \ 0 & \ 1 & \ 2 & \ \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ 2/3 \\
1 & 1 & \fbox{2} & 3 & \fbox{1/3} \\
\hline
& \ (1/2)^2 & \ \fbox{$2(1/2)^2$} & \ (1/2)^2 & \mathbb{Pr}(Y) \backslash \mathbb{Pr}(X) \\
\end{array}
$$

From the above table we see that $\mathbb{Pr}(W=2) = \mathbb{Pr}(X=1,Y=1) = 2(1/2)^2(1/3)=1/6.$

Can you do the rest?